# reading a particular tag value from XmlNode?

Tags: c#, xml

I am getting my response xml tag in xnode

```
 XmlNode xnode = service.AuthenticateUser(textBoxRegID.Text, textBoxUserName.Text, textBoxPassword.Text);
```

this xnode contains tags or the values...I need to take a particular tag value from that
then only I can continue my project using that value.

```
foreach (XmlNode item in xnode.ChildNodes)
{
  foreach (XmlAttribute attr in item.Attributes)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(attr.Value);
  }
}
```

I tried this code to get the value..but I didn´t get any result..and there are no errors.

Comment: [`XmlNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx) and [`XNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.aspx) are **two different things**.

Comment: Could you provide xml response? In your case it will be stored in xnode.OuterXml